# ggplot2, error in filling the area under lines

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have this data set and I want to fill the `area under each line`. However I get an error saying:

> Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

Additionally, I need to use `alpha` value for transparency. Any suggestions?

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
    a = rnorm(12, mean = 2, sd = 1),
    b = rnorm(12, mean = 4, sd = 2),
    month = c("JAN","FEB","MAR",'APR',"MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"))

dat$month <- factor(dat$month, 
    levels = c("JAN","FEB","MAR",'APR',"MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"), 
    ordered = TRUE)

dat <- melt(dat, id="month")

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = month, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_area(stat ="bin")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want to fill the area under each line

This means we will need to specify the `fill` aesthetic.

> I get an error saying `"Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic."`

This means we will need to delete your `stat ="bin"` code.

> Additionally, I need to use alpha value for transparency.

This means we need to put `alpha = <some value>` in the `geom_area` layer.

Two other things: (1) since you have a factor on the x-axis, we need to specify a grouping so `ggplot` knows which points to connect. In this case we can use `variable` as the grouper. (2) The default "position" of `geom_area` is to stack the areas rather than overlap them. Because you ask about transparency I assume you want them overlapping, so we need to specify `position = 'identity'`.

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = month, y = value, colour = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_area(aes(fill = variable, group = variable),
              alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can customize alpha value for each variables?

Comment: @Geo-sp Map it as an aesthetic and see `scale_alpha_discrete`, though that's an unusual approach for area plots.

Answer (score 2):

To get lines across categorical variables, use the `group` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = month, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) + 
    #geom_line(position = 'stack') +   # redundant, but this is where lines are drawn
    geom_area(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image: area plot]

To change the color inside, use the `fill` aesthetic.